# Как отключить data-toggle у виджета nav?

Tags: yii2

Собственно есть необходимость создать такое меню

```
<li class="dropdown">
     <a class="dropdown-toggleOne col-md-24 col-sm-16 col-xs-16 " href="Parrent">Parrent</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li>
                 <a data-test="1" href="Child1">Child1</a>
           </li>
           <li>
                 <a data-test="2" href="Child2">Child2</a>
          </li>
      </ul> 
</li>
```

то есть исключить каретку и `data-toggle='dropdown'` у элемента

```
<a class="dropdown-toggleOne col-md-24 col-sm-16 col-xs-16 " href="Parrent">Parrent</a>
```

Это как то можно сделать в виджете `Nav` 
через это linkOptions и dropDownOptions пробовал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я помню, Yii2 использует на фронтенде Bootstrap. Поэтому что-то отключать лучше его средствами, а не средствами Yii.

Как альтернативный вариант, можно написать свой виджет меню.

И ещё:

> `col-md-24 col-sm-16 col-xs-16`

У Bootstrap, даже в 4 версии, сетка состоит из 12 колонок, если, конечно, не используется кастомная сборка.

Comment: ДА сетка кастомная не в этом речь по у молчанию Yii2 формируется так `<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="/goods/dly_nee/" data-toggle="dropdown">` а мне надо исключить `data-toggle="dropdown"`

Comment: Можно попробовать поправить генерацию по умолчанию, если её нельзя изменить в настройках. Либо, если не хотите править стандартный виджет, написать собственный, который будет формировать меню, которое Вам нужно.

Comment: Вот я и спрашиваю как поправить можно :)

Comment: Поправить можно отыскав нужное место в коде стандартного виджета и внеся в него необходимые изменения. В любом случае направление для решения проблемы вам дано. А, дальше уж как нибудь сами....